# Can you list the keyword arguments a function receives?

Tags: python, arguments, introspection

I have a dict, which I need to pass key/values as keyword arguments.. For example..

```
d_args = {'kw1': 'value1', 'kw2': 'value2'}
example(**d_args)
```

This works fine, *but* if there are values in the d_args dict that are not accepted by the `example` function, it obviously dies.. Say, if the example function is defined as `def example(kw2):`

This is a problem since I don't control either the generation of the `d_args`, or the `example` function.. They both come from external modules, and `example` only accepts some of the keyword-arguments from the dict..

Ideally I would just do

```
parsed_kwargs = feedparser.parse(the_url)
valid_kwargs = get_valid_kwargs(parsed_kwargs, valid_for = PyRSS2Gen.RSS2)
PyRSS2Gen.RSS2(**valid_kwargs)
```

I will probably just filter the dict, from a list of valid keyword-arguments, but I was wondering: **Is there a way to programatically list the keyword arguments the a specific function takes?**

Answer (score 167, accepted):

A little nicer than inspecting the code object directly and working out the variables is to use the inspect module.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def func(a,b,c=42, *args, **kwargs): pass
>>> inspect.getargspec(func)
(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'args', 'kwargs', (42,))
```

If you want to know if its callable with a particular set of args, you need the args without a default already specified.  These can be got by:

```
def get_required_args(func):
    args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)
    if defaults:
        args = args[:-len(defaults)]
    return args   # *args and **kwargs are not required, so ignore them.
```

Then a function to tell what you are missing from your particular dict is:

```
def missing_args(func, argdict):
    return set(get_required_args(func)).difference(argdict)
```

Similarly, to check for invalid args, use:

```
def invalid_args(func, argdict):
    args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)
    if varkw: return set()  # All accepted
    return set(argdict) - set(args)
```

And so a full test if it is callable is :

```
def is_callable_with_args(func, argdict):
    return not missing_args(func, argdict) and not invalid_args(func, argdict)
```

(This is good only as far as python's arg parsing. Any runtime checks for invalid values in `kwargs` obviously can't be detected.)

Comment: Nice! I didn't know this function!

Comment: Given that the method using code objects is more or less identical, is there a benefit to having had to import one more module...?

Comment: @jmets - definitely - it's virtually always better to use a library module than to roll your own.  Also, the attributes on the code object are more internal, and are up for change (eg. note that this moved to __code__ in pyhon3).  Using the module as the interface futureproofs you  a bit more in case some of these internals ever change.  It'll also do stuff you might not have thought to do, like throw an appropriate type error on functions you can't inspect (eg. C functions).

Comment: `inspect.getargspec(f)` is deprecated since Python 3.0; the modern method is `inspect.signature(f)`.

Comment: FYI, if you want to support Cython and Python, this method does not work on a Cython'd function. The ``co_varnames`` option, on the other hand, does work in both.

Comment: This is super helpful. I had no idea of the existence of `inspect`.

Comment: re 'runtime checks for invalid values in kwargs obviously can't be detected' - what about valid kwargs keys?

Answer (score 35):

This will print names of all passable arguments, keyword and non-keyword ones:

```
def func(one, two="value"):
    y = one, two
    return y
print func.func_code.co_varnames[:func.func_code.co_argcount]
```

This is because first `co_varnames` are always parameters (next are local variables, like `y` in the example above).

So now you could have a function:

```
def get_valid_args(func, args_dict):
    '''Return dictionary without invalid function arguments.'''
    validArgs = func.func_code.co_varnames[:func.func_code.co_argcount]
    return dict((key, value) for key, value in args_dict.iteritems() 
                if key in validArgs)
```

Which you then could use like this:

```
>>> func(**get_valid_args(func, args))
```

---

if you **really need only keyword arguments** of a function, you can use the `func_defaults` attribute to extract them:

```
def get_valid_kwargs(func, args_dict):
    validArgs = func.func_code.co_varnames[:func.func_code.co_argcount]
    kwargsLen = len(func.func_defaults) # number of keyword arguments
    validKwargs = validArgs[-kwargsLen:] # because kwargs are last
    return dict((key, value) for key, value in args_dict.iteritems() 
                if key in validKwargs)
```

You could now call your function with known args, but extracted kwargs, e.g.:

```
func(param1, param2, **get_valid_kwargs(func, kwargs_dict))
```

This assumes that `func` uses no `*args` or `**kwargs` magic in its signature.

Comment: what if I want to print out "keyword" arguments "keys" only ?

Comment: In Python 3.10 use `__code__` instead `func_code`.

Answer (score 19):

For a Python 3 solution, you can use [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) and filter according to [the kind of parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter.kind) you'd like to know about.

Taking a sample function with positional or keyword, keyword-only, var positional and var keyword parameters:

```
def spam(a, b=1, *args, c=2, **kwargs):
    print(a, b, args, c, kwargs)
```

You can create a signature object for it:

```
from inspect import signature
sig =  signature(spam)
```

and then filter with a list comprehension to find out the details you need:

```
>>> # positional or keyword
>>> [p.name for p in sig.parameters.values() if p.kind == p.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD]
['a', 'b']
>>> # keyword only
>>> [p.name for p in sig.parameters.values() if p.kind == p.KEYWORD_ONLY]
['c']
```

and, similarly, for var positionals using `p.VAR_POSITIONAL` and var keyword with `VAR_KEYWORD`.

In addition, you can add a clause to the if to check if a default value exists by checking if `p.default` equals `p.empty`.

Comment: The `kind` attribute is very handy, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In Python 3.0:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import fileinput
>>> print(inspect.getfullargspec(fileinput.input))
FullArgSpec(args=['files', 'inplace', 'backup', 'bufsize', 'mode', 'openhook'],
varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(None, 0, '', 0, 'r', None), kwonlyargs=[], 
kwdefaults=None, annotations={})
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use this for a function name 'myfun':

```
myfun.__code__.co_varnames
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending DzinX's answer:

```
argnames = example.func_code.co_varnames[:func.func_code.co_argcount]
args = dict((key, val) for key,val in d_args.iteritems() if key in argnames)
example(**args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested a lot but this will work for my case:

```py
import inspect


def example(arg_1: int, arg_2: list, arg_optional="Hello", *, kwarg, kwarg_optional="Hi"):
    pass


spec = inspect.getfullargspec(example)

args_required = spec.args
args_optional = args_required[-len(spec.defaults or []):]
args_required = args_required[:-len(args_optional)]

kwargs_required, kwargs_optional = spec.kwonlyargs, (spec.kwonlydefaults or {})
kwargs_required = [key for key in kwargs_required if key not in kwargs_optional]

unlimited_args, unlimited_kwargs = bool(spec.varargs), bool(spec.varkw)
annotations = spec.annotations

print(args_required, args_optional, kwargs_required, kwargs_optional, unlimited_args, unlimited_kwargs, annotations)
```