# Python introspection: description of the parameters a function takes

Tags: python, introspection

Is there is a tool similar to `dir()` for modules that will tell me what parameters a given function takes? For instance,  I would like to do something like `dir(os.rename)` and have it tell me what parameters are documented so that I can avoid checking the documentation online, and instead use only the Python scripting interface to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`help(thing)` pretty prints all the docstrings that are in the module, method, whatever ...

Answer (score 12):

I realize that you're more interested in `help(thing)` or `thing.__doc__`, but if you're trying to do programmatic introspection (instead of human-readable documentation) to find out about calling a function, then you can use the [`inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html), as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196960/can-you-list-the-keyword-arguments-a-python-function-receives).