# How to get a functions arguments and values from outside the function?

Tags: python

I have searched a little bit to try to figure this one out but didn't get a solution that I was exactly looking for.

This is my use case:

- I would like to evaluate expressions from a functions/methods doc-string against the f/m's parameters and values, but from outside the function (when being called but outside execution of the function
- I can't statically change the source code I am evaluating (cant write in new functionality) but dynamically changing (i.e. wrapping the function or adding attributes at run-time) is acceptable
- I would prefer to stick with tools in the standard library but am willing to try external libraries if it will make the task a breeze

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
def f1(a,b):
    """a==b"""
    pass

def f2(f):
    f_locals = "get f's args and values before f is executed"
    return eval(f.__doc__,None,f_locals)

>>> f2(f1(2,2))
```

Comment: Why? You can't pass `f1(2, 2)` as an argument to another function without evaluating it; the value of `f1(2, 2)` is the return value of the f1 called with those parameters.

Comment: Is it acceptable to call it like `f2(func, *args, **kwargs)`, which in your case would be `f2(f1, 2, 2)`? Is this some kind of testing framework?

Comment: You don't get what you want from http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html for functions and code objects?

Comment: i know, bad example.  the intention is to "execute the function enough" to get the parameters and values without fully executing the function (which could modify the parameters by execution end).  its a academic project on model checking and i am trying to figure out how to evaluate pre-conditions.  i am trying to "intercept" the function call, retrieve the args/values, and evaluate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you list the keyword arguments a Python function receives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196960/can-you-list-the-keyword-arguments-a-python-function-receives)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I have no clue why you would want to do this, what you've described can be achieved with the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module. This example is as close to your original example that I can come up with.

```
from inspect import getcallargs
def f1(a,b):
   """a==b"""
   pass

def f2(f, *f_args, **f_kwargs):
    f_callargs = getcallargs(f, *f_args, **f_kwargs)
    return eval(f.__doc__, None, f_callargs)

f2(f1, 2, 2)
```

This should output `True`.

Keep in mind that this assumes a great many things about the arguments and docstrings of any such functions passed to `f2`, not the least of which is that none of the examined functions are malicious or malformed. Why don't you want to call functions normally, and why don't you want to change functions?

**Edit**: As Pajton pointed out, `getcallargs` is more appropriate here, and removes the calls to both `dict` and `zip`. The above code has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: Of course `getcallargs(func[, *args][, **kwds])` would be better than `getargspec`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here's an alternative without inspect module.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8-unix -*-
"""
This is a sample implementation of Inline.pm (Perl) in Python.

Using @inline decorator, it is now possible to write any code
in any language in docstring, and let it compile down to executable
Python code at runtime.

For this specific example, it simply evals input docstring, so
code in docstring must be in Python as well.
"""

# Language compiler for MyLang
class MyLang:
    @classmethod
    def compile(self, docstring):
        # For this example, this simply generates code that
        # evals docstring.
        def testfunc(*arg, **kw):
            return eval(docstring, None, kw)
        return testfunc

# @inline decorator
def inline(lang):
    def decorate(func):
        parm = func.__code__.co_varnames[0:func.__code__.co_argcount]
        fgen = lang.compile(func.__doc__)
        def wrap(*arg, **kw):
            # turn all args into keyword-args
            kw.update(dict(zip(parm, arg)))
            return fgen(**kw)
        return wrap
    return decorate

@inline(MyLang)
def myadd(a, b):
    """a + b"""

print(myadd(1, 9))
print(myadd(b = 8, a = 2))
print(myadd(a = 3, b = 7))
```