# Separating **kwargs for different functions

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

Given a higher order function that takes multiple functions as arguments, how could that function pass key word arguments to the function arguments?

*example*

```
def eat(food='eggs', how_much=1):
    print(food * how_much)


def parrot_is(state='dead'):
    print("This parrot is %s." % state)


def skit(*lines, **kwargs):
    for line in lines:
        line(**kwargs)

skit(eat, parrot_is)  # eggs \n This parrot is dead.
skit(eat, parrot_is, food='spam', how_much=50, state='an ex-parrot') # error
```

`state` is not a keyword arg of `eat` so how can skit only pass keyword args relevant the function that it is calling?

Comment: No doubt there are ways to accomplish this, but I think you're approaching this from the wrong angle. What would you do if two of your functions take a keyword arg with the same name, and you want to pass different values to the two functions? Best to just pass in dicts of keyword args explicitly. Potentially each argument would be (say) a two-element tuple consisting of a function and its dict of keyword args.

Comment: That's probably the best solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can filter the `kwargs` dictionary based on `func_code.co_varnames` (in python 2) of a function:

```
def skit(*lines, **kwargs):
    for line in lines:
        line(**{key: value for key, value in kwargs.iteritems() 
                if key in line.func_code.co_varnames})
```

In python 3, `__code__` should be used instead of `func_code`. So the function will be:

```
def skit(*lines, **kwargs):
    for line in lines:
        line(**{key: value for key, value in kwargs.iteritems() 
                if key in line.__code__.co_varnames})
```

Also see: [Can you list the keyword arguments a function receives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196960/can-you-list-the-keyword-arguments-a-python-function-receives)

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary thanks, good point, as always helpful. I've also added a link to the related thread.

Comment: What is the benefit of inspect.getargspec(func).args over line.func_code.co_varnames?  Does then inspect module just provide more options that we don't need in this case?

Comment: @ptwales `inspect` really [uses](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/inspect.py#L804) the same `func_code` under the hood. `inspect` is generally speaking the tool for the job that provides an interface to the "magic" involved in object inspection.

Answer (score 8):

If you add `**kwargs` to all of the definitions, you can pass the whole lot:

```
def eat(food='eggs', how_much=1, **kwargs):
    print(food * how_much)


def parrot_is(state='dead', **kwargs):
    print("This parrot is %s." % state)


def skit(*lines, **kwargs):
    for line in lines:
        line(**kwargs)
```

Anything in `**kwargs` that isn't also an explicit keyword argument will just get left in `kwargs` and ignored by e.g. `eat`.

Example:

```
>>> skit(eat, parrot_is, food='spam', how_much=50, state='an ex-parrot')
spamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspamspam
This parrot is an ex-parrot.
```

Answer (score -1):

`def sample(a,b,*,c=0):
    print(a,b,c)`

## * -> is before argument is  args and after argument is kwargs(keyword arguments)

`sample(1,2,c=10)
sample(a=1,b=2,c=1) # this also work 
sample(1,2,c) # TypeError: sample() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`