# Call with keyword argument only on Python 3.3 or higher

Tags: python

I'm trying to use [`logging`'s `SMTPHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler). From Python 3.3 on, you can specify a `timeout` keyword argument. If you add that argument in older versions, it fails. To get around this, I used the following:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 3):
    smtp_handler = SMTPHandler(SMTP_SERVER, FROM_EMAIL, TO_EMAIL, SUBJECT, timeout=20.0)
else:
    smtp_handler = SMTPHandler(SMTP_SERVER, FROM_EMAIL, TO_EMAIL, SUBJECT)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/196960/3001761

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than test for the version, use exception handling:

```
try:
    smtp_handler = SMTPHandler(SMTP_SERVER, FROM_EMAIL, TO_EMAIL, SUBJECT, timeout=20.0)
except TypeError:
    # Python < 3.3, no timeout parameter
    smtp_handler = SMTPHandler(SMTP_SERVER, FROM_EMAIL, TO_EMAIL, SUBJECT)
```

Now you can conceivably upgrade your standard library in-place with a patch or a backport module and it'll continue to work.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
kargs = {}
if sys.version_info >= (3, 3):
    kargs['timeout'] = 20.0

smtp_handler = SMTPHandler(SMTP_SERVER, FROM_EMAIL, TO_EMAIL, SUBJECT, **kargs)
```

**UPDATE**: The idea of `try/catch` of other answers is nice, but it assumes that it fails because of the `timeout`  argument. Here I present an extra-smart test for the availability of the argument. What if future versions of this class add more and more optional arguments? (Disclaimer: not claimed as portable):

```
if 'timeout' in SMTPHandler.__init__.__code__.co_varnames:
    kargs['timeout'] = 20.0
```

Comment: or `kargs = {'timeout': 20.0} if sys.version_info >= (3, 3) else {}` in ternary form

Answer (score 1):

Here is another slightly different approach:

```
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 3):
    # patch in timeout where available
    from functools import partial
    SMTPHandler = partial(SMTPHandler, timeout=20.0)
```

Now in the rest of the code you can just use:

```
smtp_handler = SMTPHandler(SMTP_SERVER, FROM_EMAIL, TO_EMAIL, SUBJECT)
```

and know that the `timeout` argument is being used if available. This does still rely on static version checking, but means that all of the version-specific config is in one place and may reduce duplication elsewhere.