# How can I get keyword/positional arguments of any method in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

As I am developer of `Python` and works at different different technologies.

So sometimes I really feel that there should be a `method` which can tell both the `KEYWORD ARGUMENT` and `POSITIONAL ARGUMENTS`of any method.

Example:

```
response(url="http://localhost:8080/core",data={"a":"12"},status=500)
```

Response have many `keyword/positional arguments` like `url,data, status`.

There can be many more keyword arguments of **response method** which I do not mentioned in above example. So I want to know all total number of keyword argument of a method.

So if anyone knows any method in **Python** which can tell about keyword argument please share it.

Comment: You can actually specify the value for positional arguments also as keyword arguments. Do you want them as well?

Comment: There is an answer here that covers this sort of thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196960/can-you-list-the-keyword-arguments-a-python-function-receives

Comment: i Just want to know total number of  keyword arguments of a mehtod. So that i can use them as per my requirement.

Comment: Hmmm, probably you can explain the actual problem. There might be a better/easy solution to it.

Comment: [inspect.Signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature)? It still won't help you if signature is defined as `callable(*args, **kwargs)`, which is perfectly fine in Python.

Comment: Inspect tells the received arguments of a method not tell the default arguments of a method.

Answer (score 1):

Try `inspect` module:

```
In [1]: def a(x, y , z): pass
In [2]: import inspect
In [3]: inspect.getargspec(a)
Out[3]: ArgSpec(args=['x', 'y', 'z'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

or use decorator:

```
def a(f):
    def new_f(*args, **kwds):
        print "I know my arguments. It:"
        print "args", args
        print "kwds", kwds
        print "and can handle it here"
        return f(*args, **kwds)
    return new_f
@a
def b(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

b(x=1, y=2)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. But, I already know about inspect module. It is helpful for receiving arguments not for default method arguments of python.