# Is there a neat (pythonic?) way to use named parameter defaults in Python given a condition?

Tags: python, named-parameters

I have a function with some named parameters, and a dictionary that contains keys with those names, as well as some other keys.  I want to call the function with values from the dictionary.

- I can't use `**data` because Python will raise `TypeError: unexpected keyword argument` because of the extra keys.
- The dict might not contain certain keys, so I can't reference the keys without checking that they exist (and I don't want to pass a default from `get`).
- I can't rewrite the function because it is in a separate library.

How can I unpack only the keys that match the function parameters?

```
def do_something(arg1=None, arg2=''):
    ...

data = {'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2, 'other': 3}

# doesn't work if key doesn't exist
do_something(arg1=data['arg1'], arg2=data['arg2'])

# too verbose, hard to extend
if 'arg1' in data:
    do_something(arg1=data['arg1'], arg2=data['arg2'])
else:
    do_something(arg2=data['arg2'])
```

Comment: `do_something(**d)`?

Comment: Also related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python

Comment: @YOU: No, the `d` contains more keys than the ones I need to pass to the function.

Comment: I don't believe this question is a dupe, as I can't simply use dictionary key unpacking. I have added extra content to the question. I have voted to re-open this question. Thanks!

Comment: [extremely relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/196997/5323213)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, I just dug this out of one of my projects

```
def call_with_optional_arguments(func, **kwargs):
    '''
    calls a function with the arguments **kwargs, but only those that the function defines.
    e.g.

    def fn(a, b):
        print a, b

    call_with_optional_arguments(fn, a=2, b=3, c=4)  # because fn doesn't accept `c`, it is discarded
    '''

    import inspect
    function_arg_names = inspect.getargspec(func).args

    for arg in kwargs.keys():
        if arg not in function_arg_names:
            del kwargs[arg]

    func(**kwargs)
```

In your case, it could be used like:

```
call_with_optional_arguments(do_something, **data)
```

--

(If you're wondering about the name, I used this to fire callback functions that the user of my library would pass in. 'optional' in this case means that `func` doesn't have to accept all the arguments I'm calling with)

Comment: thanks @joerick. I was hoping for some nice syntactical sugar, but it seems that there may not be any. I guess I could write a function to suite my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Just riffing here...

```
do_something(**{ k: data[k] for k in ['Arg1', 'Arg2'] if k in data })
```

That looks pretty nasty though.